# imp.find_module() which supports zipped eggs

Tags: python, python-import

[imp.find_module()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.find_module) does not find modules from zipped eggs.

How can **find** modules which can come from both places: directories or zipped eggs? It is important in my case that I can provide a `path` argument like imp.find_module() supports it.

**Background**

Somehow packages get installed twice in our environment. As zipped egg and as plain files. I want to write a check which tells me if a module is installed twice. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23990989/633961

Comment: What if your module is deep within a package hierarchy inside a zipped egg?  What path do you want in that case?  There *is* no file directly equivalent to the module you've requested.

Comment: @Kevin imp.find_module() only finds "toplevel" modules. For example you can find "os" but you can't find "path" (like from "os.path"). I just want a find_module() that works like the import statement of the python interpreter does. The interpreter loads zipped eggs.

Comment: The import mechanism in 2.x is incompletely exposed.  Under 3.x, you could get what you want with `importlib`; `imp` is deprecated.  Unfortunately, this also means the whole thing is substantially more complicated than `imp` ever was.

Comment: @Kevin thank you for the hint. `importlib` exists even in Python2.7. It is a subset, but maybe better than nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming Python 2, the information I think you need is in [PEP 302 - New Import Hooks](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) (the PEP is outdated for Python 3, which is completely different in this regard).

Finding and importing modules from ZIP archives is implemented in [zipimport](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html), which is "hooked" into the import machinery as described by the PEP. When PEP 302 and importing from ZIPs were added to Python, the `imp` modules was not adapted, i.e. `imp` is totally unaware of PEP 302 hooks.

A "generic" `find_module` function that finds modules like `imp` does **and** respects PEP 302 hooks, would roughly look like this:

```
import imp
import sys

def find_module(fullname, path=None):
    try:
        # 1. Try imp.find_module(), which searches sys.path, but does
        # not respect PEP 302 import hooks.
        result = imp.find_module(fullname, path)
        if result:
            return result
    except ImportError:
        pass
    if path is None:
        path = sys.path
    for item in path:
        # 2. Scan path for import hooks. sys.path_importer_cache maps
        # path items to optional "importer" objects, that implement
        # find_module() etc.  Note that path must be a subset of
        # sys.path for this to work.
        importer = sys.path_importer_cache.get(item)
        if importer:
            try:
                result = importer.find_module(fullname, [item])
                if result:
                    return result
            except ImportError:
                pass
    raise ImportError("%s not found" % fullname)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Provide a simple CLI for `find_module` above.
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--path", action="append")
    parser.add_argument("modname", nargs='+')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    for name in args.modname:
        print find_module(name, args.path)
```

Note, though, that the result from finding a module in a ZIP archive looks quite different to what `imp.find_module` returns: you'll get a `zipimport.zipimporter` object for the particular ZIP. The litte program above prints the following when asked to find a regular module, a built-in module and a module from a zipped egg:

```
$ python find_module.py grin os sys
<zipimporter object "<my venv>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grin-1.2.1-py2.7.egg">
(<open file '<my venv>/lib/python2.7/os.py', mode 'U' at 0x10a0bbf60>, '<my venv>/lib/python2.7/os.py', ('.py', 'U', 1))
(None, 'sys', ('', '', 6))
```

Comment: The call of importer.find_module(fullname) does not pass the `path` argument. This causes to return false results, if path is not sys.path

Comment: I use this now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697497/pip-installs-package-twice

Comment: I've updated the code. It will now correctly honor `path`. My point was to explain what's going on.

Comment: You pass in `path` to `importer.find_modul()`. But AFAIK the argument `path` gets ignored from zipimporter :-(

Comment: Yes, I know it is ignored by `zipimporter`. But there could be *other* import hooks installed that use `path`. Insofar my answer addresses your question more generally, as the code will find any module the Python interpreter would find in a similar way the real `import` implementation does (modulo the difficulties posed by the intricate interplay of import.c, PEP 302 etc. in Python 2).

Comment: BTW, if you are worried that `zipimporter.find_module()` ignoring `path` is problematic, because you want the code to honor the path you give it: this is not the case. The `zipimporter` objects in the importer cache are already bound to one specific ZIP archive/egg, and will lookup the module in question there. The protocol introduced with PEP 302 is somewhat inconsistent with the `imp` API in this regard.